# Adding new ListTile item on click

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have created `method` and `widget`, right now my code is working fine because data is `static`, i want to add new item in `ListTile` when i press Add Button.

**method:**

```
Card listSectionMethod(String title, String subtitle, IconData icon) {
  return new Card(
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      subtitle: Text(subtitle),
      trailing: Icon(
        icon,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

**Widget:**

```
Widget listSection = Container(

   margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 210),
              child: ListView(
                children: [
                   Column(
                   children: [
                      listSectionMethod("TITLE 1", "hello i am subtitle one",Icons.forward),
                      listSectionMethod("TITLE 2", "hello i am subtitle two",Icons.forward),  
                   ],
                  ),
                ],),
);
```

**Button:**

```
FloatingActionButton(
 onPressed:()
 {
    print("clicked"); //i want to add new item from here, when i press on click
 }, 

 child:Text("+"),
 backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
),
);
```

Comment: We can complete your code, and even indicate if your code is `Stateless` or` Stateful`, because the solution will depend on this.

Comment: it's stateless i edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look to add a new item you must do the following:

**Assuming your screen is a StatefulWidget**

```
class SomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomePageState createState() => _SomePageState();
}

class _SomePageState extends State<SomePage> {
     var _listSection = List<Widget>();

     @override
     void initState() {
        super.initState();
        // Here initialize the list in case it is required
        _listSection.add(
          listSectionMethod("TITLE 1", "hello i am subtitle one", Icons.forward),
        );
        _listSection.add(
          listSectionMethod("TITLE 2", "hello i am subtitle two", Icons.forward),
        );
     }
 }
```

**Widget:**

```
    Widget listSection() {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 210),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: this._listSection, // ----> Add this
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
     }
```

**Button:**

```
    FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
               // Here we add a new item to the list
              _listSection.add(
                listSectionMethod("New TITLE", "hello from click", Icons.forward),
              );
            });
          },
          child: Text("+"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
       );
```

Comment: widget is stateless

Comment: class is stateless not stateful

Comment: Ok, so what you are doing is creating a `Stateless` `Widget` and then passing the data from another `Widget`?

Comment: i have method and list section widget and a button which i added in question, then i am using list section widget inside main.dart body: , and main.dart  extends stateless widget

Comment: It would be nice to take a look at this flutter code lab [Code lab](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312778/flutter-invalid-refrence-to-this-expression

Answer (score 1):

Before I start, you need to make sure you're using a `StatefulWidget`, not a `StatelessWidget` so we can take advantage of the `setState()` method.

First, define a class member variable. You could put it on top of the class, or where ever else as long as it's not inside a function.

```
List<Widget> _listOfWidgets = [];
```

Second, let's modify your FAB (Floating Action Button) code:

```
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: () {
    print("fab clicked");
    _addItemToList(); // new method
  }, 
  child:Text("+"),
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
);
```

Let's now define the new method which will use our class member variable.

```
_addItemToList() {
  List<Widget> tempList = _listOfWidgets; // defining a new temporary list which will be equal to our other list
  tempList.add(Text("I'm an added item!"));
  setState(() {
    _listOfWidgets = tempList; // this will trigger a rebuild of the ENTIRE widget, therefore adding our new item to the list!
  });
}
```

Let's modify your existing code to work with our new code:

```
Widget listSection = Container(
   margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 210),
   child: ListView(
     children: [
       Column(
         children: _listOfWidgets,
       ),
     ],
   ),
);
```

There you go!

Comment: Thanks, i am using stateless widget, we can't do this in stateless?

Comment: You actually could do this in a StatelessWidget if you wanted to take advantage of Streams and a `StreamBuilder` which are a bit more complicated. Using a `StatefulWidget` suits your needs way better and there's no need to over-engineer it.

Comment: i was hoping to pass values as parameter to my method when i click on add button. eg. after press i wanted to add,listSectionMethod("TITLE 1", "hello i am subtitle one",Icons.forward),

Comment: Yes, you can, I'm just giving you an example of how you could do it. I'm not going to do it for you, but I can help you do it on your own. You can easily pass parameters to the `_addItemToList()` method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59312778/flutter-invalid-refrence-to-this-expression