# Flutter invalid refrence to 'this' expression

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i am trying to add item in list when i click on add button, all code is ok, but i am getting error invalid reference to `this` expression. i am using `stateful` widget.

```
List<Widget> _listSection = [];
            body: Container(
              child: Stack(
                children: [

                  FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      _listSection.add(
                        listSectionMethod(
                            "title three", "hello from click", Icons.forward),
                      );

                      setState(() {});
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    Widget listSection = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 210),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: this._listSection, // ----> ERROR HERE
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**List Section Method:**

```
Card listSectionMethod(String title, String subtitle, IconData icon) {
  return new Card(
    child: ListTile(
      title: Text(
        title,
        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
      subtitle: Text(subtitle),
      trailing: Icon(
        icon,
        color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Just remove the `this`

Comment: undefined name _listsection

Comment: Your variable has a capital S

Comment: i tried _listSection and listSection both and i got error it is not defined,

Comment: i have defined variable under, class MyApp1 extends State<MyApp> {
  List<Widget> _listSection = [];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**change this:**

```
Widget listSection = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 210),
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: this._listSection,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

**for this:**

```
Widget listSection() {
        return Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 210),
          child: ListView(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: this._listSection, 
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
     }
```

Comment: got it, i was defining widget out of class, that was working fine with just ui, for stateful i guess i need to define it inside class, after that this would work,

Comment: Thank you for following

Comment: i added it in class and it got fix , but how i can add it in another file and call it in main.dart file with reference, this would not work there.

Comment: Do you want to share the widget to use it in another class?

Comment: i have created another files named, method.dart, i want to define all methods there, and then i imported it main.dart, if i defined Widget listSection() in methods.dart , i want to use it in main file by calling listSection(), right now i can't it gives same error . because it consider it out of class. like it was happening before.

Comment: I understand, but to do that I would have to pass the method to the method you are trying to execute. Because being a method outside the class does not have access to the properties that the class has.

Comment: thanks for understanding, then my main.dart file will get alot of code, how i can keep it clean?

Comment: If you want to have the separate widgets in another folder, this is fine, but you must pass them the data, because when you have no status, you don't have to know the information where it comes

Comment: using routes? i was importing it as widget and using it by name and it was working fine, but i guess we can not include methods like that.

Comment: i have seen some people creating model file ui file and main file in there projects, i need to see that too i guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204153/discussion-between-juan-e-londono-t-and-fayakon).