# Why does this FAB not update the state?

Tags: user-interface, flutter, dart, state

I have followed as best I can this question: [Adding new ListTile item on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59276419/adding-new-listtile-item-on-click?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Though it is not necessarily as reproducible as it could be, I've created something that compiles, but does not run as expected:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(SeedBank());

class SeedBank extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      ),
      home: Seeds(),
    );
  }
}

class Seeds extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SeedsState createState() => SeedsState();
}

class SeedsState extends State<Seeds> {
  var _seedSection = List<Widget>();

  Card seedSectionMethod(String title, String subtitle) {
    return new Card(
      child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(subtitle),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
    );
  }

  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _seedSection.add(
      seedSectionMethod("Leek", "Bulgaarse Reuzen - Lincoln"),
    );
    _seedSection.add(
      seedSectionMethod("Kale", "Jardin mix"),
    );
    _seedSection.add(
      seedSectionMethod("Sunflower", "Helianthus Red"),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Seed Bank'),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: this._seedSection,
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text("+"),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _seedSection.add(
              seedSectionMethod("New Seed", "With notes"),
            );
          });
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The desired behaviour is:

- on app startup, that the three 'cards' with the seeds are populated.
- on button press, a new 'card' is added with the values `"new Seed"` and `"with notes"`.

I expect I have missed something basic in flutter about setting state (only started yesterday), but I'm in a rut about where to go next to understand it more.

### V2:

using @andrea689, I can compile, but have hit the same problem again:

```
class SeedsState extends State<Seeds> {
  var _seedSection = List<Widget>();

  var _seeds = [
    ["Leek", "Bulgaarse Reuzen - Lincoln"],
    ["Kale", "Jardin mix"],
    ["Sunflower", "Helianthus Red"],
  ];

  Card seedSectionMethod(String title, String subtitle) {
    return new Card(
      child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(subtitle),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Seed Bank'),
      ),
      body:  ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _seedSection.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return seedSectionMethod(_seeds[index][0], _seeds[index][1]);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text("+"),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _seeds.add(["New Seed", "With notes"]);
          });
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is this how the class is supposed to look? It's now not adding a new item again.

## Final Solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(SeedBank());

class SeedBank extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.lightGreen,
      ),
      home: Seeds(),
    );
  }
}

class Seeds extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  SeedsState createState() => SeedsState();
}

class SeedsState extends State<Seeds> {
  var _seeds = [
    ["Leek", "Bulgaarse Reuzen - Lincoln"],
    ["Kale", "Jardin mix"],
    ["Sunflower", "Helianthus Red"],
  ];

  Card seedSectionMethod(String title, String subtitle) {
    return new Card(
      child: ListTile(
          title: Text(
            title,
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          subtitle: Text(subtitle),
          trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert)),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Seed Bank'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _seeds.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return seedSectionMethod(_seeds[index][0], _seeds[index][1]);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text("+"),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            setState(() {
              _seeds.add(["New Seed", "With notes"]);
            });
          });
        },
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `_seedSection` is modified, you have to use `ListView.builder`

```dart
ListView.builder(
     itemCount: _seedSection.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return _seedSection[index];
     },
),
```

Moreover, it is better to store in state only the values and make the widget inside `itemBuilder`.

```dart
var _seeds = [
    ["Leek", "Bulgaarse Reuzen - Lincoln"],
    ["Kale", "Jardin mix"],
    ["Sunflower", "Helianthus Red"],
  ];

ListView.builder(
     itemCount: _seeds.length,
     itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return seedSectionMethod(_seeds[index][0], _seeds[index][1]);
     },
),

setState(() {
     _seeds.add(["New Seed", "With notes"]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you mean: `void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _seedSection.add(
      seedSectionMethod("Leek", "Bulgaarse Reuzen - Lincoln"),
    );
    _seedSection.add(
      seedSectionMethod("Kale", "Jardin mix"),
    );
    _seedSection.add(
      seedSectionMethod("Sunflower", "Helianthus Red"),
    );
  }`
Should be moved into the `FloatingActionButton(....)` call in the scaffold?

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood fully, please see V2 edit in question. thanks for the help understanding :)

Comment: Should `itemCount: _seedSection.length` be `itemCount: _seeds.length`?

Comment: @DaveRGP yes, sorry for copy/paste mistake!

Answer (score 2):

try like this.

```
body: ListView.builder(
  itemCount: this._seedSection.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => this._seedSection[index],
),
```

Here is working demo.
https://dartpad.dev/43a5b08327ed0f64fd084947873a3e52

Comment: This works. could you add a little more to help me understand why?

Comment: ListView.builder, when you are dynamically creating list. in your case you are dynamically adding item into your list.

ListView work when your list is not updating, 

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this:

```
body: ListView(
  children: this._seedSection.map((data) {
    return data;
  }).toList(),
),
```

Comment: This also works. Could you please explain a little why it does and what I missed?